# Northern Towns - a cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Directions are relative, except where they're not.

[image: Grid]

```
Across
1   Fifty-fifty chance of Lisa slipping on parrot mucus (2,4,2,3)
7   Coming back from college, one is substantially dilute (3)
9   A bunch of these can create impact in game (5)
10  Northwestern town where Remains go after partial veto (9)
11  Trouble at mill, primarily due to head of accounting working without supervision (9)
12  Religious opinion held by one expressing disbelief at Wakefield church revival (5)
13  Wrote novel after cold: new high point for northern city (2,5)
15  Informant is rank amateur (4)
18  Margaret Atwood's literary bestseller originally involved this, but there's no sign of it in Gilead (4)
20  Ultimate rescue: lose one cat, gain setter (7)
23  Good cobbler goes back to making last (5)
24  Seen 26 in park (9)
26  Teen magazine wrote about bitter age (5,4)
27  Man seen around hospital in northwestern city (5)
28  Doctor reported you in online game (3)
29  In half a day, ten knocked up! (11)

Down
1   Pledge to return note before borrowing without necessary principal (8)
2   Priestly: one that gets thanks from fly (8)
3   One of America's top ten mistakes: it's taken out and shot (5)
4   One who judges members of legal profession, head down, practicing rite ... (7)
5   ... and seen cavorting in northwestern suburb (7)
6   T' triumph! (4,5)
7   Strung-out infantry (6)
8   He fibs about northeast maintaining proportion (6)
14  A paperback set in the middle of nowhere, one northern city (9)
16  Any sound gents in offensive building? (8)
17/21   For crossword Muppets, Miss Piggy's head may lead to nosebleeds (8,6)
19  Swear at 9 from northeastern city? Spooner says they are used to "Shoot!" (7)
20  Mature setter finally issued correction (7)
21  See 17
22  Checked the server was online, hoping Edgar hadn't erased the contents (6)
25  First newsreader to grow up up north is in a show, carrying a bat and fencing (5)
```

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but @ 17/21 isn’t it too broad/not allowed to have one cryptic clue 2 unrelated words/phrases

Comment: @TrojanByAccident The answer is one phrase of two words, and the definition is of that phrase.

Comment: Is the "a" at the end of 5d, after the enumeration, deliberate?

Comment: @Rupert I see...

Comment: Is the misspelling of Atwood as Attwood deliberate?

Comment: Did you make all this yourself?  If so, wow.  If not, I believe this site requires attribution.

Comment: We do indeed require attribution for material taken from elsewhere, but I don't see anything to indicate that Rupert didn't make this himself. (I'm enjoying it so far. About 60% done.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Both typos. One fat finger (a) and the other not checking a spelling because I thought I knew it.

Comment: All me own work, @Exal

Comment: @RupertMorrish  In which case, WOW!  Sorry for the rudeness.  You are clearly a talented puzzle maker!

Comment: @Exal [blush] Glad you enjoyed it.

Comment: this deserves far more attention and upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [image]

A few confessions:

> I don't understand the wordplay of 12a. I'm not entirely sure of 25d, but it seems convincing enough to put in. (N/AGEThe Walking Dead, and all the pictures of him online show him carrying a bat. Not sure about "fencing", but I guess if I were familiar with the show then all would become clear.)

Other than that, I'm confident about everything in the grid.

Comment: the definition of 7a is from Wikipedia. 18a is indeed an indirect anagram, though a very easy one, and the surface pleased me too much not to use it. I hope you'll forgive me.

Comment: Your answer for 13a is wrong. The city in question is much further north than Bangkok.

Comment: Happy to forgive 18a -- I liked it too. Thanks for the heads-up on 13a; will reconsider.

Comment: Ah, duh, of course. Fixing now.

Comment: 13a is now correct. I will put up a hint for 25d later.

Comment: 25d: you may want to consider the usual purpose of his adornment to the implement.

Comment: 12a: You're going to kick yourself when you see it.

Comment: 12A has the word in the lines of the clue..

Comment: D'oh, so it does. And I hadn't noticed the barbed wire, but now I have. Thanks :-).